# Border display issue, not sure how to resolve

Tags: html, css, border

Part of my web application has a issue with the outline of a section.

Currently this is happening:
[image]
[image]

Both pictures show the title having a space before it, and the second shows a space at the bottom.  Occasionally these spaces aren't there, but in that case the bottom gets wonky still.  The problem seems to be in the length of the titles, as shorter titles have the bottom overlapping problem and longer titles have the space problem, however, in all cases there is a space before the title at the top.

Here is the code that generate the sub-section (it is vbscript printing HTML):

```
    Response.Write "<!--BEGIN DATA SUB-SECTION TABLE************************************************************************************************************************-->" & chr(10)
    Response.Write "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<tr>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<td colspan=5>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<!--BEGIN SUB-SECTION HEADER TABLE************************************************************************************************************************-->" & chr(10)
    Response.Write "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<tr>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<td width='5' height='9' align='left' valign='bottom'>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<img border='0' src='"&strDirectory&"images/new_line_left.gif' width='4' height='10'></td>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<td width='1%' align='left' nowrap><h2 class='fff'>"&Name&"</h2></td>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<td class='fff'>&nbsp;</td>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<td width='5' height='9' align='right' valign='bottom'>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<img border='0' src='"&strDirectory&"images/new_line_right.gif' width='5' height='10'></td>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "</tr>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "</table></td>" & Chr(10)
    Response.Write "<!--END SUB-SECTION HEADER TABLE************************************************************************************************************************-->" & chr(10)
    Response.Write "</tr>" & Chr(10)
```

Now, what the coders who originally wrote this code wants to do is to write a series of exceptions to fix the problem, basically making the reusable code hard-coded to the values we already use.  I hate this idea for obvious reasons, but because of my own inexperience with vbscript and HTML, I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Just in case anyone needs it, the css for the 'fff' class:

```
 td.fff {background:url("Maintenance/images/new_line_center.gif") repeat-x bottom;}
```

The new_line_center.gif is just the side border:  [image]

Comment: style="display:block" on images?

Comment: Your main problem is using tables for the page layout and images for the border, when all these things can be done in a single `<div>` with a CSS border with `border-radius`. You don't need a fix, you need a rewrite.

Comment: @Spudley, would that allow the title to appear within the border?  The overall look needs to stay the same.  IMHO, the whole app needs rewritten and some standards put in place, but that's a loosing battle atm.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus - yes, it's perfectly possible to have text overlaying the top of a border like that using pure CSS. it's just a question of using `position:absolute` and place it over the top of the border. It's quite a commonly used effect.

Comment: @Spudley Thank you.  I have been brought up to speed with web technologies very quickly, and it will be some time before I get the nuances down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is probably introducing the `Chr(10)` between the `<td>` and the image.  I'd try removing that so the cell is rendered like this:

```
<td><img src="..." /></td>
```